# Convert String to Response (Serenity)

Tags: json, response, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to do the following:

Currently I'm using Serenity (which uses Rest Assured) to perform some API requests, and I correctly obtain the responses and treat them (getResponse.getBody blablabla), resulting in a treated String.
Now, what I want to do is "convert" that String to a Response type and treat it again.

Is that possible? I can't find any information about it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot do this, as `String` type cannot be casted to `Response`.